# having issuses using sqoop import tool from oracle to cassandra

Tags: cassandra, sqoop

I am trying to load data from oracle table to cassandra table. I tried to follow the same steps mentioned in document from Datastax website on Running the Sqoop demo - https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaSqpDemo.html

Here, I am using oracle database instaed of mysql.  Using Datastax enterprise 5.0.2.

```
dse sqoop cql-import --connect 'jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@//ip_address_of_the_host:PORT/SERVICE_NAME' --table ORACLE_TABLE_NAME --cassandra-keyspace npa_nxx --cassandra-table npa_nxx_data --cassandra-host IP_ADDRESS_CASSANDRA --cassandra-port 9042 --cassandra-column-mapping  npa:npa,nxx:nxx,latitude:lat,longitude:lon,state:state,city:city
Hadoop functionality is deprecated and may be removed in a future release.
Note: /tmp/sqoop-xxxx/compile/4657cfc531e9676b9013e057157bf522/SSFS_STAGE02_NPA_NXX.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
ERROR 13:45:08,987 Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Failed to read the table metadata
        at com.datastax.bdp.sqoop.SqoopUtil.setCqlImportOptions(SqoopUtil.java:186)
        at com.datastax.bdp.sqoop.CqlImportJob.configureOutputFormat(CqlImportJob.java:120)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:240)
        at com.datastax.bdp.sqoop.SqoopUtil.importTable(SqoopUtil.java:587)
        at com.datastax.bdp.sqoop.SqlManagerAdapter.importTable(SqlManagerAdapter.java:222)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:601)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:57)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: --cassandra-column-mapping contains an SQL column city that does not exist in the SQL table or query
        at com.datastax.bdp.sqoop.SqoopUtil.validateColumnConsistency(SqoopUtil.java:312)
        at com.datastax.bdp.sqoop.SqoopUtil.setCqlImportOptions(SqoopUtil.java:168)
        ... 13 more
```

I have tested the jdbc connection for oracle and looks good.

Please help me to understand the issue and any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks
Raghav

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
--cassandra-column-mapping contains an SQL column city that does not exist in the SQL table or query
```

Suggests that your Oracle Table was not created correctly, you should double check that it has the correct schema.

Comment: Thanks RussS for the reply.  I have created oracle table using SqlDeveloper. I can see all the columns present in both oracle and cassandra table.

Comment: Doesn't look like they match, I believe they are case sensitive

Comment: Thank you RussS.    Yes they are case sensitive.  I changed column mapping and now, I  am facing different issue:

Answer (score 0):

Here is the DDL for Oracle table:

```
CREATE TABLE "SCHEMA_NAME"."NPA_NXX" 
   (    "NPA_NXX_KEY" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NPA" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "NXX" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "LAT" FLOAT(126), 
    "LON" FLOAT(126), 
    "LINETYPE" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "STATE" VARCHAR2(2 BYTE), 
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(36 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "NPA_NXX_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("NPA_NXX_KEY")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "XXXXXX_DATA"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "XXXXX_DATA" ;
```

Cassandra keyspace and table:

```
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE npa_nxx WITH REPLICATION = 
         {'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'Analytics':1};

cqlsh> CREATE TABLE npa_nxx.npa_nxx_data (npa int, nxx int, 
         latitude float, longitude float, state text, city text, 
         PRIMARY KEY(npa, nxx));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dse sqoop cql-import --connect 'jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@//ip_address_of_the_host:PORT/SERVICE_NAME' --table ORACLE_TABLE_NAME --cassandra-keyspace npa_nxx --cassandra-table npa_nxx_data --cassandra-host IP_ADDRESS_CASSANDRA --cassandra-port 9042 --cassandra-column-mapping    npa:NPA,nxx:NXX,latitude:LAT,longitude:LON,state:STATE,city:CITY


Hadoop functionality is deprecated and may be removed in a future release.
Note: /tmp/sqoop-tmhmadm/compile/06a746beb5d4af8ac13b60568fedbcbd/SSFS_STAGE02_NPA_NXX.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
WARN  11:23:58,503 Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of -1.
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)

java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of -1.
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)

java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of -1.
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)

java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of -1.
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)

attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000001_0: 11:24:15,977 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000001_0: 11:24:15,978 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000001_0: 11:24:15,979 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/etc/dse/cassandra/logback.xml]
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000001_0: 11:24:16,412 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000001_0: 11:24:16,418 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[/etc/dse/cassandra/logback.xml]] every 60 seconds.
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000001_0: 11:24:16,418 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000001_0: 11:24:16,432 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.JMXConfiguratorAction - begin
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000001_0: 11:24:16,617 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000001_0: 11:24:16,624 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [SYSTEMLOG]
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000001_0: 11:24:17,683 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@74294adb - Will use zip compression
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000001_0: 11:24:17,835 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000001_0: 11:24:17,919 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SYSTEMLOG] - Active log file name: cassandra.logdir_IS_UNDEFINED/system.log
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000001_0: 11:24:17,919 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SYSTEMLOG] - File property is set to [cassandra.logdir_IS_UNDEFINED/system.log]
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000001_0: 11:24:17,921 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000001_0: 11:24:17,921 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [DEBUGLOG]
 .
 .
 .

 .

attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,116 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.thinkaurelius.thrift] to ERROR
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,116 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,116 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [SolrValidationErrorAppender]
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,117 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@276438c9 - Will use zip compression
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,117 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@276438c9 - Large window sizes are not allowed.
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,118 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@276438c9 - MaxIndex reduced to 21
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,118 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,120 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SolrValidationErrorAppender] - Active log file name: cassandra.logdir_IS_UNDEFINED/solrvalidation.log
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,120 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SolrValidationErrorAppender] - File property is set to [cassandra.logdir_IS_UNDEFINED/solrvalidation.log]
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,120 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [SolrValidationErrorLogger] to ERROR
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,120 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [SolrValidationErrorLogger] to false
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,120 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [SolrValidationErrorAppender] to Logger[SolrValidationErrorLogger]
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,120 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.metrics.MetricsWriteEventListener] to DEBUG
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,120 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.solr.core.CassandraSolrConfig] to WARN
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,120 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore] to WARN
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,120 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers] to WARN
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,120 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.solr.handler.component] to WARN
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,120 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher] to WARN
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,120 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.solr.update] to WARN
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,120 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.lucene.index] to INFO
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,120 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.cryptsoft] to OFF
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,120 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: 11:24:50,121 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@588df31b - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
attempt_201610061121_0001_m_000002_2: INFO  11:24:51,231  NativeCodeLoader.java:43 - Loaded the native-hadoop library
ERROR 11:25:28,355 Error during import: Import job failed!
```